# Terraform AZ CLI local exec command limitation

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to run offset AZ cli commands in Terraform apart of my AKS cluster infrastructure to automate the tedious tasks. One of those being running the `az vmsss extention set` command to add certs to each node. To do this, I am using a null resource with a local exec provisioner. This is the [AZ cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss/extension?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vmss-extension-set) command I am using.

The part of the command that I would like to leverage and what Terraform does not like is the `'{"commandToExecute":...}'` with a curl.

Example of what I would like to do:

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az vmss extension set --vmss-name my-vmss --name customScript --resource-group my-group version 2.0 --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions provision-after-extensions NetworkWatcherAgentLinux VMAccessForLinux  settings '{"commandToExecute": "echo testing"}'"
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Error: Missing newline after argument

  on test.tf line 3, in resource "null_resource" "test":
 3:     command = "az vmss extension set --vmss-name my-vmss --name customScript --resource-group my-group version 2.0 --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions provision-after-extensions NetworkWatcherAgentLinux VMAccessForLinux  settings '{"commandToExecute": "echo testing"}'"

An argument definition must end with a newline.
```

Are there any known workarounds to be able to run more complex commands using the local-exec provisioner?

Terraform version: 0.13

Comment: Try to use `EOT` or `-EOT` includes your comments. Take a look at https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-literals

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this issue, and thanks to @Nancy Xiong, this is how you would proceed using heredoc style...

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    az vmss extension set --vmss-name my-vmss --name customScript --resource-group my-group version 2.0 --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions provision-after-extensions NetworkWatcherAgentLinux VMAccessForLinux  settings '{"commandToExecute": "echo testing"}'
    EOT
  }
}
```